# R: Sorting data.frame by a column and conditionally deleting of rows

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I've got a `data.frame` in R with sample data that looks like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(NAME=c("NAME1","NAME1","NAME1","NAME1","NAME2","NAME2","NAME2","NAME2") , SURVEY_YEAR =c(1947,1958,1978,1987,1963,1991,2004,1993), REFERENCE_YEAR=c(1934,1947,1974,1947,1944,1987,1993,1987), VALUE=c(10,15,13,20,-2,7,12,-19))

dat
       NAME SURVEY_YEAR REFERENCE_YEAR VALUE
    1 NAME1        1947           1934    10
    2 NAME1        1958           1947    15
    3 NAME1        1978           1974    13
    4 NAME1        1987           1947    20
    5 NAME2        1963           1944    -2
    6 NAME2        1991           1987     7
    7 NAME2        2004           1993    12
    8 NAME2        1993           1987   -19
```

How could I sort it first by `REFERENCE_YEAR` (from lowest to highest):

```
   NAME SURVEY_YEAR REFERENCE_YEAR VALUE
1 NAME1        1947           1934    10
2 NAME1        1958           1947    15
3 NAME1        1987           1947    20
4 NAME1        1978           1974    13
5 NAME2        1963           1944    -2
6 NAME2        1991           1987     7
7 NAME2        1993           1987   -19
8 NAME2        2004           1993    12
```

And then if a year in `REFERENCE_YEAR` is the same, delete the one which covers the longer period (from `REFERENCE_YEAR` to `SURVEY_YEAR`) from `dat` and then write the deleted rows into a new `data.frame`?

The data.frame with the sample data should look like this in the end:

```
  NAME SURVEY_YEAR REFERENCE_YEAR VALUE
1 NAME1        1947           1934    10
2 NAME1        1958           1947    15
3 NAME1        1978           1974    13
4 NAME2        1963           1944    -2
5 NAME2        1991           1987     7
6 NAME2        2004           1993    12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BondedDust left an elegant answer. My answer is far longer than his. But, let me leave it.

```
dat %>%
    arrange(REFERENCE_YEAR) %>%
    mutate(gap = SURVEY_YEAR - REFERENCE_YEAR) %>%
    arrange(REFERENCE_YEAR, gap) %>%
    group_by(NAME, REFERENCE_YEAR) %>%
    filter(gap == gap[1]) %>%
    arrange(NAME,REFERENCE_YEAR)

#   NAME SURVEY_YEAR REFERENCE_YEAR VALUE gap
#1 NAME1        1947           1934    10  13
#2 NAME1        1958           1947    15  11
#3 NAME1        1978           1974    13   4
#4 NAME2        1963           1944    -2  19
#5 NAME2        1991           1987     7   4
#6 NAME2        2004           1993    12  11
```

Comment: tried your plyr example but what I get is an error that it couldn't find function %<%?

Comment: @redshoe I used `dplyr`. `%>%` is an operator you use with the package.

Comment: thank you for the information! this works great!! Even solved the problems I have above with Bonded Dust's solution!

Comment: I would like to use the result for further processing but whenever I call dat up again, it is in the initial state? Is there a way with dplyr that only the displayed result is written to a new data.frame?

Comment: @redshoe In this example, your dat is still the original. If you want to assign the outcome to another object, you can do it. e.g., foo <- dat %>% arrange() %>% etc.

Comment: Sorry about that. Shortly after asking I got to the solution myself, was kind of confused with the dplyr syntax at first but it isn't that hard once you really look close :) thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to sort on both REFERENCE_YEAR & SURVEY_YEAR. The the items with the longest interval will be sorted first and will be selected by the duplicated() function as NOT-duplicated, so just leave them out using logical indexing:

```
> dat2 <- dat[ order(dat$REFERENCE_YEAR, dat$SURVEY_YEAR) , ]
> dat2 <- dat2[ !duplicated( dat2$REFERENCE_YEAR) , ]
> dat2
   NAME SURVEY_YEAR REFERENCE_YEAR VALUE
1 NAME1        1947           1934    10
5 NAME2        1963           1944    -2
2 NAME1        1958           1947    15
3 NAME1        1978           1974    13
6 NAME2        1991           1987     7
7 NAME2        2004           1993    12
```

Comment: thank you! I also added dat$NAME into the first line after 'order()' so that it is also ordered by groups (NAME) if there are more than 2 different groups (NAME)

Comment: And if there were two items in a group that was "adjacent" to a group ending or beginning with the same year, you may need to use `!duplicated(dat2[ , c("REFERENCE_YEAR", "NAME") ]`

Comment: The problem with this method is that you order the whole data by the REFERENCE_VALUE and then search for the duplicated values and if it is duplicated it deletes them. But how could I apply this (do exactly this) but by group (split by NAME)?

Comment: Oh right. `duplicated` wouldn't do it. An `ave` solution would be needed. You should post your questions with the necessary complexity so that errors can be detected by testing.

Comment: You are right, its my fault! Next time I'll try to provide better sample data and I'll try to be more accurate. Thank you  for contributing!